# Django set initial pre-filled field value

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two models:

```
class Budget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField(default=now)
    datecompleted = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Expenses(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    budget = models.ForeignKey(Budget, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='budget_expense')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

and my Form as follow

```
class ExpenseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateTimeField(
        widget=forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'datetime-local'}),
        label='Data', input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'])

    class Meta:
        model = Expenses
        fields = ('name', 'quantity', 'budget', 'category', 'date')
```

and now I trying to create an instance of Expense with pre-filled (existing) Budget instance with below code:

```
def expense_add(request, budget_id=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        budget = get_object_or_404(Budget, pk=budget_id)
        form = ExpenseForm(initial={'budget': budget})
        return render(request, 'budget/expense-create.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = ExpenseForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('list')
        return render(request, 'budget/expense-create.html', {'form': form})
```

url pattern:

```
    path('budget/<int:budget_id>/expense-create', views.expense_add, name='expense-create-new'),
    path('budget/expense-create', views.expense_add, name='expense-create-new'),
```

but, as you may guess there is nothing in budget field inside my formfield.

P.S. budgetdetail.view:

```
def budget_detail(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Budget, pk=pk)
    expenses_list = Expenses.objects.filter(budget_id=instance.pk)
    budget_id = instance.pk
    return render(request, 'budget/budget-detail.html',
                  {'instance': instance, 'expenses_list': expenses_list})
```

Please help. Thank you all!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [foreign key as initial value not passed to the ModelForm in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226793/foreign-key-as-initial-value-not-passed-to-the-modelform-in-django)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it's a similar issue and I tried to replace (initial={'budget': budget.name}) to (request.POST or None, initial={'budget': budget,}) but result same - empty field

Comment: Hello @Ches_Ter can you share updated code by making an [edit]

Comment: @AnkitTiwari hi! Done. Check please

Comment: Hello @Ches_Ter you're passing `request.POST ` inside youe `request.method == "GET"` try to pass like this `ExpenseForm(initial={'budget': budget})`

Comment: @AnkitTiwari, I tried and nothing changed...

Comment: Hello @Ches_Ter try to print budget and check that it contain any values.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari nothing. Empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244915/discussion-between-ches-ter-and-ankit-tiwari).

Comment: Hello @Ches_Ter if it's empty then your initial values will be empty and your form will render empty data

Comment: But what is wrong with it, why it's empty? Let me know please if you need more details

Comment: I think you've to check for id you're passing as an argumnet don't give default value as **None**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the views.py where you set the initial value of budget. It expects either a budget object or the id of the budget object but you give the name of the object. So you can fix it by removing the `.name` from the 4th line.

The corrected view:

```py
def expense_add(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        budget = get_object_or_404(Budget, pk=pk)
        form = ExpenseForm(initial={'budget': budget})
        return render(request, 'budget/expense-create.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = ExpenseForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('list')
        return render(request, 'budget/expense-create.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank you. I removed it. Nothing changed. Just copied your code and pasted in to my view. Reload local server. Same empty field as result

Comment: Did you insert the id of an existing budget object in the url?

Comment: Added picture with html. Did you mean that Id?

Comment: path('budget/<int:pk>/expense-create', views.expense_add, name='expense-create-new'), But what I mentioned above is id of expense instance not budget I guess)))

Comment: It should be of a budget instance, since the expense doesn't exist yet and when created  it will have a foreign key to a budget instance.

Comment: Thanks, yeah. I think I’m beginning to understand now, but, how I can pass ... one more Id?)))

Comment: I don't understand where do you want an extra id.

Comment: Sorry. I meant on a last html screen where: href="{% url 'expense-create-new' instance.pk %}" (marked red) if I change - instance.pk on something else then Exception Value I got

Comment: Is instance an instance of budget? Because it should be. Can you also share the budget view (that renders budget-detail.html) for more clarification?

Comment: `def budget_detail(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Budget, pk=pk)
    expenses_list = Expenses.objects.filter(budget_id=instance.pk)
    return render(request, 'budget/budget-detail.html',
                  {'instance': instance, 'expenses_list': expenses_list})`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! In my url pattern there was another `path('budget/<int:pk>/expense-create', ExpenseCreateView.as_view(), name='expense-create'),` which is cover or overwrite my view or something I suppose...once i comment it `def expense_add` - worked!!